# SQL select all data that past 45 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have "alerts" table with date field - targetDate.

I would like to select all data that past 45 days.

I tried the code below but it's not return any results...

```
SELECT userID, refID, `targetDate`
FROM alerts
WHERE type = 'travelSoon'
AND DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , targetDate ) > 45
```

Table

```
 id     userID  type    refID   createDate  targetDate  lastSendDate    sent    valid
1   26  travelSoon  NO  2018-05-02 13:54:25 0000-00-00  2018-05-02 00:00:00 0   1
2   26  travelSoon  NO  2018-05-02 13:55:50 2018-06-01  0000-00-00 00:00:00 0   1
3   26  travelSoon  DK  2018-05-02 13:56:12 2018-12-01  0000-00-00 00:00:00 0   1
4   26  travelSoon      2018-05-02 13:59:50 0000-00-00  0000-00-00 00:00:00 0   1
5   26  travelSoon      2018-05-02 14:00:09 2018-08-01  0000-00-00 00:00:00 0   1
6   26  travelSoon  DK  2018-05-02 14:00:48 2018-08-01  0000-00-00 00:00:00 0   1
7   26  travelSoon      2018-05-02 16:45:18 2018-05-01  0000-00-00 00:00:00 0   1
8   26  travelSoon  RO  2018-05-02 16:45:45 2018-04-01  0000-00-00 00:00:00 0   1
```

Comment: What is targetDate datatype?

Comment: @DT - date ....

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle...?

Comment: The NOW() function returns the current date in MySQL. Use that, and a hard-coded timestamp for 45 days to get a timestamp of the oldest possible entries. Then SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp > var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MSSQL `DATEDIFF(interval, date1, date2)` returns interval of  `date2 - date1`.

Interval should be selected from this list:

```
- year, yyyy, yy = Year
- quarter, qq, q = Quarter
- month, mm, m = month
- dayofyear = Day of the year
- day, dy, y = Day
- week, ww, wk = Week
- weekday, dw, w = Weekday
- hour, hh = hour
- minute, mi, n = Minute
- second, ss, s = Second
- millisecond, ms = Millisecond`
```

Then use:

```
SELECT userID, refID, `targetDate`
FROM alerts
WHERE type = 'travelSoon'
AND DATEDIFF(day, targetDate, GETDATE() ) > 45
```

For MySQL you can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,date1,date2)` which returns interval of  `date1 - date2`.

`unit` can be selected from `MICROSECOND (microseconds), SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER, or YEAR.`

```
SELECT userID, refID, `targetDate`
FROM alerts
WHERE type = 'travelSoon'
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CURDATE( ), targetDate) > 45
```

Comment: I tried your example and got this error: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: in mysql datediff there are only 2 parameters required not the day parameter

Answer (score 2):

Using `DATEDIFF()` is a bad idea.  It blocks the ability to use indexes, and there is an alternative that doesn't...

```
SELECT *
  FROM alerts
 WHERE type = 'travelSoon'

   AND targetDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -45, GETDATE())    -- SQL Server

   AND targetDate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 45 DAY     -- MySQL
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ecdc0/6

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT userid, refid, `targetdate` 
FROM   alerts 
WHERE  type = 'travelSoon' 
       AND Datediff(Curdate(), targetDate) < 45 -- or <=45 
       AND Datediff(Curdate(), targetDate) > 0
```

Online Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ecdc0/4/0

If you only use `Datediff(Curdate(), targetDate) < 45` condition, it may return both past and future dates. Please refer the below table.

```
Today: May 10, 2018

+----+-------------+
| id | targetDate  |  DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), targetDate) 
+----+-------------+
|  2 | -- |                             -22 
|  3 | -- |                            -205 
|  5 | -- |                             -83 
|  6 | -- |                             -83 
|  7 | 2018-05-01  |                               9 
|  8 | 2018-04-01  |                              39 
+----+-------------+
```

To avoid this, you can use another condition like this...

```
Datediff(Curdate(), targetDate) > 0
```

Comment: Hi DT - It's good, but i want only the data that have more than 45 days. not between 0-45. that's mean March, February, January (2018)

Comment: will this works? `TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY , targetDate, CURDATE( ) ) >45` ?

Comment: @Roi, if that's the case, yes. your condition will work. By the way, in your example, there are no data to match that condition, right? Refer this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bfb49/16/0

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI Standard syntax would be:

```
SELECT userID, refID, `targetDate`
FROM alerts
WHERE type = 'travelSoon' AND
      targetDate >= CURRENT_DATE - interval '45 day' AND
      targetDate <= CURRENT_DATE;
```

In MySQL (which your syntax suggests:

```
SELECT userID, refID, `targetDate`
FROM alerts
WHERE type = 'travelSoon' AND
      targetDate >= CURRENT_DATE - interval 45 day AND
      targetDate <= CURRENT_DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userID, refID, `targetDate`
FROM alerts
WHERE type = 'travelSoon'
AND targetDate >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 45 DAY )
```